# increase size of stack in nasm OS X intel 64

Tags: macos, stack, nasm

How I can increase size of stack in assembly (NASM OS X intel64)

I used `.STACK 4096` before `section .data` but return this error

```
 error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels

 error: parser: instruction expected
```

Please guide me.

Comment: NASM doesn't have a `STACK` directive. You can modify the stack pointer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the stack size with the linker - `ld`  For OSX: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1419/_index.html

The default stack size on OSX is 8 Megabytes, is that not large enough for you?